# How to have TypeScript syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I don't know if it's the right place to ask but how should I write my code block to have highlighting for TypeScript language?

I use this:

````
```typescript
```
````

But it doesn't work:

```
const foo = 'bar';
type Type = { [key: string]: string | number | any[] };
```

Comment: `lang-typescript`

Comment: The OP is using code fences (triple backticks). In that case, the `lang-` prefix is *not* used. The `lang-` prefix is only when using the XML comment style `<!-- language: lang-typescript -->`

Comment: Why is my question closed? I know how syntax highlighting work on SO thanks but it's only working for language like `css`, `html`, `javascript`. What should I wrote to have it for `typescript`?

Comment: Buried in that linked post is a [link to the *prettify* supported lang list](https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work), which doesn't appear to include TypeScript. Highlight.js [*does* have TS support](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) however, so it's very possible that it'll come in the future.